# Building Alljoyn stack for win 10

Tags: alljoyn

Am trying to build alljoyn stack cloned from git in win10 using the procedure mentioned in alljoyn link
https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/windows

It starts throwing error for msajtransport.h.  I downloaded from git and placed in working directory.

Then it threw error for missing msajapi.lib. I found that too placed in working directory. Still there are more errors.

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Got any stack trace for exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Install windows 10 SDK. Specifically 10.0.1.143930.0 version. I ran into the same problem, after installing that version of SDK, MSAJTransport.h could be found under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\um"